# Padding and margin not showing up?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get padding and a margin around my text labelled "content." I tried two different methods (1) using ".content" and (2) using "p{}" None of them seem to work, but when I add "color: purple;" to either method, it works. It seems that only the margin and padding attribute isn't working. Is there a default that I need to override? Thanks!

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dogworldstyle.css">
</head>
<body>


<h1>
Dog Info
</h1>
<h2>
History
</h2>
<p class="content">
Dogs have been around for over 15,000 years, and today we know them as "man's best friend."
Today, The American Kennel Club (AKC) recognizes 195 breeds of dogs as of 2020, but for the simplicity
of this demo, we will cover three of the author's favorites: 
<a href = "poodle.html"> poodles</a>, 
<a href = "corgi.html"> corgis</a>, and 
<a href = "shiba.html"> shibas</a>. Watch the brief video below.
</p>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4doKA0VpKgc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="5" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>


<h2>
Characteristics
</h2>

<p class="content">
Dogs are capable of feeling empathy, making eye contact, understanding gestures (pointing, 
hands up, etc.) and so much more. This makes them amazing companions at working various
jobs including:
</p>

<ul>
<li>hunting</li>
<li>therapy work</li>
<li>search and rescue</li>
<li> herding</li>
</ul>

<p class="infolinks">
<a href = "https://www.akc.org/expert-advice/training/working-dogs-jobs-dogs-can/"> This</a>
link lists more unique jobs tailored to dogs.
</p>

<h2>
Additional Info
</h2>

<p class="infolinks">
To see a full list of the breeds recognized by the AKC, click
<a href = "https://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/"> here</a>. 
For more information on the history of dogs, click 
<a href = "https://historycooperative.org/the-history-of-dogs/"> here</a>.
</p>
```

CSS file

```
@charset "ISO-8859-1";

header li {
display: inline-block;
}

h1{
background-color: #F4C2C2;
opacity: 0.6;
text-align: center;
border: 3;
border-bottom-style: solid;
}

h2{
border-left: solid #ff80c0;
}

.content{
width: 600;
margin: 50;
padding: 70;
}

form {
background-color: #FFE6EE;
}
```

Comment: Numbers maybe not enough px, %, rem/em should be defined next to margins ?
You can read a tutorial how css should work 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: `margin`, `padding`, `border` and `width` need a *unit of measurement* next to them. For example, `margin: 50px` instead of `margin: 50`.